# Updating variable value with PowerShell script in Azure DevOps .yml file

Tags: .net, powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I'm struggling with artifacts File Version of my project. The idea is to input Azure DevOps pipeline run number (which is e.g. 20230506.1 - yyyyMMdd.X) into FileVersion property of .csproj file. Due to FileVersion limit to uint16 (Windows) it can't be passed to format like that: 1.0.20230506.1, becouse part '20230506' exeeds the uint16.
So, I had an idea, to divide the pipeline run number into substrings using PowerShell task.
Initially I have had BUIL_NUMBER variable based on Build.BuildNumber and hardcoded variables in my ci.yml file like this:

```
variables:
  BUILD_NUMBER: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
  BUILD_YEAR: '2'
  BUILD_MONTH: '2'
  BUILD_DAY: '2'
  BUILD_DAILYNO: '7'
```

And further in ci.yml there is PowerShell script code:

```
jobs:
- job: BuildAndTest
  displayName: Build and test
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host "Hello World"
        $BUILD_YEAR = $env:BUILD_NUMBER.Substring(0, 4)
        $BUILD_MONTH = $env:BUILD_NUMBER.Substring(4, 2)
        $BUILD_DAY = $env:BUILD_NUMBER.Substring(6, 2)
        $BUILD_DAILYNO = $env:BUILD_NUMBER.Substring(9)
        Write-Host $BUILD_YEAR
        Write-Host $BUILD_MONTH
        Write-Host $BUILD_DAY
        Write-Host $BUILD_DAILYNO
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_YEAR;isoutput=true]$BUILD_YEAR"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_MONTH;isoutput=true]$BUILD_MONTH"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_DAY;isoutput=true]$BUILD_DAY"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_YEAR;isoutput=true]$BUILD_YEAR_TEMP"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_MONTH;isoutput=true]$BUILD_MONTH_TEMP"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_DAY;isoutput=true]$BUILD_DAY_TEMP"
```

Due to research and other stackoverflow question asked by people, I thought, that this script should update each variable with produced substring. But it does not work. Please, help.

I've tried to move PowerShell script to other tasks, e.g. Assembly-Info-NetCore@3. But I failed.

Comment: "But it does not work" - can you elaborate?

Comment: "Due to FileVersion limit to uint16 (Windows) it can't be passed to format like that: 1.0.20230506.1, becouse part '20230506' exeeds the uint16." Where are you encountering this issue? Don't store the value as an integer, it's not a number.